# How can I know elasticseach storage usage from AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I have a elasticsearch instance on AWS. I wonder how I can find the storage usage from AWS console. From the general view I can see the total size of the storage volume as below screenshot. But how I can see the storage usage? My elasticsearch instance is sitting in a VPC so I can't connect to it easily.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using AWS Elasticsearch Service, you can see your cluster's disk usage on the dashboard: https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/es/home (replace `eu-west-1` with the cluster's region).
[image]

If you want to check the free space per instance, select your cluster on the dashboard and click "Instance Health".
[image]

You will find the free storage for each of your data instances there.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Elastic Seach Dashboard then

Select Cluster/Domain -> Cluster Health -> Total free Storage

[image]

[image]